# Solution for IPC when firewall is activated and no rules can by added

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ipc

For my application, I decided to implement the "Jump List" (added with W7 - Windows7CodePack).
The problem with JumpList, you cannot (or I ignore how to code) make an action on your active application. Link in menu open a new instance of application and this communicate informations with the first instance (*play music*, *pass to next video*, ...)

I tested Socket and WCF but I blocked by firewall and parts of code on the web I find is insufficient to implement correction or for test a another solution in my app.

I want only execute an action on my active application when a click on a task, in the jumplist.

Anybody have a idea ?

Comment: Have you looked at `NamedPipeClientStream` and `NamedPipeServerStream` ?

Comment: It seems to work, I just have to test in a TSE environment.
I go back to give the result :)